# Calculate the quotient space of three real projective planes

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Consider the following quotient space: Take $a,b \in RP^2$, $Y = RP^2 \times \{1, 2, 3\}$, and $X$ = the quotient space of $Y$ quotient by $(b,1) = (a,2)$,  $(b,2) = (a,3)$,  $(b,3) = (a,1)$. How do we calculate the fundamental group of $X$?

I can calculate it by first calculating the fundamental group of the wedge sum of two real projective planes using Van-Kampen. Then use Van-Kampen again for the three of them together. Is there easier way to do this?

Comment: I guess there is not. Anyway, it doesn't seem too complicated to me via Seifert-Van-Kampen theorem.

Comment: Do you know Van Kampen for groupoids ? This is more adapted here since if you try to glue the wedge sum to the third one, you have to gluing points, not just one, and so the best way to handle this situation is with groupoids. One way to see how classical Van Kampen falls short, is that there is a "$\mathbb{Z}$" factor that appears, which isn't easy to see from classical Van Kampen

Comment: Is the result the free product of three copies of $Z/2Z$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a matter of clarity, I denote $(a,i)$ and $(b,i)$ by $a_i$ and $b_i$ for $i=1,2,3$, respectively.

Lets call $Z$ the quotient space obtained from $Y$ by identifying $b_1$ with $a_2$ and $b_2$ with $a_3$. First we can compute the fundamental group of $Z$. By applying Van Kampen twice, we get 
$$\pi_1(Z)\simeq\langle c_1,c_2,c_3\vert c_1^2=c_2^2=c_3^2=1\rangle,$$ 
where $c_i$ corresponds to the generator of the fundamental group of $RP^2\times \{i\}$.

Now $X$ is obtained from $Z$ by identifying $a_1$ and $b_3$. Let 
$$p:Z\to X$$ 
be the corresponding quotient map and let $\overline{a_1}=p(a_1)=p(b_3)$. The map $p$ induces a morphism
$$p_*:\pi_1(Z,a_1)\longrightarrow \pi_1(X,\overline{a_1}).$$
We would be happy to say that $p_*$ is onto, but it's not. This is because if  $\tilde{\gamma}:[0,1]\to Z$ is a path from $a_1$ to $b_3$, its image $\gamma=p(\tilde{\gamma})$ is a loop in $X$, but it won't be in the image of $p_*$. Let $t$ be some object (I just need $t$ to be some object generating a copy of $\Bbb Z$), there is a natural homomorphism
$$f:\langle t\rangle\longrightarrow \pi_1(X,\overline{a_1})$$
sending $t$ to $[\gamma]$. Then $p_*$ and $f$ induce a morphism 
$$\psi:\pi_1(Z,a_1) * \langle t\rangle\longrightarrow \pi_1(X,\overline{a_1}).$$ 
I claim that $\psi$ is an isomorphism. If you admit this (which is far from trivial, but reasonable if you picture what $X$ looks like) you get 
$$\pi_1(X)\simeq\langle c_1,c_2,c_3,t~\vert~ c_1^2=c_2^2=c_3^2=1\rangle.$$

---

I know that $\psi$ is an isomorphism from a *quotient* version of Van Kampen that I learned [here](http://analysis-situs.math.cnrs.fr/Theoreme-de-van-Kampen-version-fermee.html) (unfortunately it is in French). In this reference they also call it the *HNN-version* of Van Kampen but I haven't found any reference to this specific theorem by searching with these words. If you want to prove that $\psi$ is an isomorphism, you can do something like this:

**$\psi$ is onto:** Take $U_1=X-\{\overline{a_1}\}$ and $U_2=p(V_1\cap V_2)$ where $V_1$ and $V_2$ are two open sets of $Z$ that deform retract onto $a_1$ and $b_3$, respectively. $U_1$ and $U_2$ are two open sets that cover $X$. Take a path $\alpha:[0,1]\to X$. Then you can decompose $\alpha$ as the concatenation 
$$\alpha=\alpha_1\cdot\alpha_2\cdots\alpha_{n-1}\cdot\alpha_n$$
such that $\alpha_i$ is a path in $U_1$ or in $U_2$. Then use the fact that $p:Z-\{a_1,b_3\}\to U_1$ is an homeomorphism to express each path $\alpha_i$ with image in $U_1$ as a combination of $\gamma$ and of elements of $\pi_1(Z)$. This kind of technique is very similar to the proof of the classical theorem of Van Kampen.

**$\psi$ is one-to-one:** You can use the covering of $X$ by $$\tilde{X}=RP^2\times \Bbb Z/_{b_i\sim a_{i+1}}.$$ Take some combination of $\gamma, c_1, c_2$ and $c_3$ which is trivial in $X$. You can picture what the lift will look like in $\tilde{X}$ in terms of the coefficient of the combination, and you should understand that the combination must be trivial because the lift is trivial in $\tilde{X}$.

I hope this helps! I didn't add much detail at the end but I can add some later if you want. I can add drawings to clarify the situation too if you'd like.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!! That is very helpful!